# WordPress Ajax call to get value from database and set in input field based on another input

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to make a dynamic form when some field will automatic depends on user input.  for example.

**mySql Data row**

```
+-------+----------------+
|br_code| br_name        |
+-------+----------------+
| 1057  | BANANI         |
+-------+----------------+
| 1065  | BANANI BAZAR   |
+-------+----------------+
| 1073  | PRIME OFFICE   |
+-------+----------------+
```

I have two input field like this

```
<input type="number" name="br_code" id="br_code"  placeholder="Branch Code"/>
<input type="text" name="br_name" id="br_name" disabled/>
```

so if I input the `br_code` how can I populate `br_name` on other field.

to achieve this What I try

**jQuery**

```
jQuery('#br_code').change(function($) {
   $('#br_name').attr('disabled', true);
   $('#br_name').val("<?php echo($br_name);?>")
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$tablename = $wpdb->prefix."sbl_employee";
//getting branch name from database
$br_name = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT br_name FROM $tablename WHERE br_code = '$br_code'" );
====Need help to call Wordpress Ajax call===
```

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your theme's functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_brnamereturner', 'brnamereturner' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_brnamereturner', 'brnamereturner' );

function brnamereturner() {
global $wpdb;
if(empty($_GET["br_code"])) return;
    $br_code=intval( $_GET['br_code'] );
    $tablename = $wpdb->prefix."sbl_br_name";
    $rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT br_name from $tablename WHERE br_code = $br_code");
    foreach ($rows as $row) { 
        echo $row->br_name;
    }
    wp_die(); 
}
```

In your jQuery, use this:

```
jQuery('#br_code').change(function($) {
   $('#br_name').attr('disabled', true);
   var data = {
    'action': 'brnamereturner',
    'br_code': jQuery('#br_code').val()
};
   jQuery.get("<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );?>", data, function(response) {
        $('#br_name').val(response);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I found this error on console `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: i have updated the answer with error fix. Check it again. if still fail, then you need some debugging in browser console and let me know which line of the code gives this error. Or type here URL where i can see the error.

Comment: response return null value . Also I try `post` instead of `get`

Comment: okay, then it is possible that your SQL query is wrong.  (don't try post, use get, because my code is designed for "get"). Try to print raw sql query with this code:  echo $wpdb->prepare("SELECT br_name FROM $tablename WHERE br_code = %s",$br_code);   and  make sure that the query is correct.

Comment: I have updated your answer and change the `$wpdb` query and its working now thanks for the help man.